# Angular directive not displaying any values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive that is not showing any values, even though when I break on the function, the vm variable has everything when each directive row is created.

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('sales.directives')
        .directive("viewPayment", viewPayment);

    function viewPayment() {
        return {
            controller: 'ViewPaymentController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: 'pages/viewPayment.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                payment: '=',
                paymentDetails: '=',
                setCurrentPayment: '&',
                currentPaymentId: '=',
                openLineItemDrawer: '&'
            }
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('sales')
        .controller('ViewPaymentController', viewPaymentController);

    viewPaymentController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function viewPaymentController($scope) {
        var vm = $scope;

        vm.details = _(vm.paymentDetails).where({ 'paymentId': vm.payment.paymentId }).value();
        vm.revisionCount = getPaymentCount();
        vm.showRevision = vm.revisionCount > 0;
        vm.isCurrentPayment = false;
        vm.showEffectiveDate = vm.payment.paymentType === 'ePayment';

        $scope.$watch('vm.currentPaymentId', setIsCurrentPayment);

        function getPaymentCount() {
            return vm.details.length - 1;
        }

        function setIsCurrentPayment(currentPaymentId) {
            vm.isCurrentPayment = currentPaymentId === vm.payment.paymentId;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Can you include viewpayment.html

Comment: Is the module created in another place? I always use [] on the first time to declare module: .module('sales.directives', [])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the "controllerAs" and changing all of the vm. to $scope. fixed the issue.